# Raw Javascript version of .click()

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I have with jQuery:

```
if ($('#vote_c').length > 0) {
    $('#vote_button').show().click();
}
```

I am trying to re-write it so it uses raw javascript:

```
if (document.getElementById('vote_c').length > 0) {
    // what goes here
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('vote_c').length` id is unique, so this function selects only one single element, no need in `.length`.

Comment: @Cheery Not only that, but length will be undefined.

Comment: (ID bla bla) also, have you tried `document.dispatchEvent(event);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// cache lookup
var vote = document.getElementById('vote_c');
// using truthy/falsy value to determine existence
// proper test would be (vote !== null)
if (vote) {
    // this is probably closest to what .show() does
    // .show actually seems to track what the initial
    // computed display state for the element was and
    // along with .hide, toggles between the initial
    // state and 'none'.
    vote.style.display = '';
    // mimicking .click() is done any number of ways
    // but the easiest is below:
    vote.onclick(); // call any registered handlers for the click event;
    //
    // OR (second easiest way) you could define a click event:
    //
    var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
        "view": window,
        "bubbles": true,
        "cancelable": true
    });
    // and then "dispatch" that event to the targeted
    // element which should trigger the handlers
    vote.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (document.getElementById('vote_c')) {
    var btn = document.getElementById('vote_button');
    btn.style.display = "inline"; //show
    btn.click() //click
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('vote_button').onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById('vote_button').style.display = 'block';
};
```

Oh, my bad. I did not see the if statement, but it should point you in the right direction.